# How to concatenate strings in python?

Tags: python, string, concatenation, jira, jql

I am doing automation in python for jira with the addition of jql search inside the service As a result: two JQL queries, one to search for "closed tickets" and the second to search for "created tickets"

But as a result, I can't add rows now.

```
#Day 0 - current day , Day '-1'  - Yesterday 
jql_day = ['','-1','-2','-3']
jql_list_one_str = []
jql_list_two_str = []

action = ['resolved','created']

for i in jql_day:    
   jql_str = 'project = MRCHNT AND '+ action[0]+' >= startOfDay(' + i + ')', 'project = MRCHNT AND '+ action[1]+' >= startOfDay(' + i + ')'
   jql_list_one_str.append(jql_str)
   jql_str_2 = 'AND '+ action[0] +' <= startOfDay(' + i + ')','AND '+ action[1] +' <= startOfDay(' + i + ')'
   jql_list_two_str.append(jql_str_2)

# jql_request = [' '.join(x) for x in zip(jql_list_one_str[1:], jql_list_two_str[:-1])]# Split list
# jql_request.insert(0,jql_list_one_str[0])


print(jql_list_one_str,jql_list_two_str)
```

Expected Result:

```
1 list resolved:

'project = MRCHNT AND resolved >= startOfDay()'
'project = MRCHNT AND resolved >= startOfDay(-1) AND resolved <= startOfDay()'
'project = MRCHNT AND resolved >= startOfDay(-2) AND resolved <= startOfDay(-1)'
'project = MRCHNT AND resolved >= startOfDay(-3) AND resolved <= startOfDay(-2)'
```

```
2 list created:

'project = MRCHNT AND created >= startOfDay()
'project = MRCHNT AND created >= startOfDay(-1) AND created <= startOfDay()'
'project = MRCHNT AND created >= startOfDay(-2) AND created <= startOfDay(-1)'
'project = MRCHNT AND created >= startOfDay(-3) AND created <= startOfDay(-2)'
```

I got two lists inside with tuples.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqORP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqORP.png)

"second result"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLmmk.png)

Comment: use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). Example:  `jql_str_2 = f"AND {action[0]} <= startOfDay({i}), AND {action[1]} <= startOfDay({i})"`

Comment: HI! Im trying add # jql_request = [' '.join(x) for x in zip(jql_list_one_str[1:], jql_list_two_str[:-1])]# Split list # jql_request.insert(0,jql_list_one_str[0]) for my strings to be like in the condition (I added an image to the question just now)

Comment: update image in question

Comment: don't post images. Update the code with the proposed use of f-strings. Then if you have a problem, put the traceback of the error you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use f-strings to resolve this issue.

```
jql_day = ['','-1','-2','-3']
jql_list_one_str = []
jql_list_two_str = []

action = ['resolved','created']

for i in jql_day:    
   jql_str = [f'project = MRCHNT AND {action[0]} >= startOfDay({i})', f'project = MRCHNT AND {action[1]} >= startOfDay({i})']
   jql_list_one_str.append(jql_str)
   jql_str_2 = [f'AND {action[0]} <= startOfDay({i})', f'AND {action[1]} <= startOfDay({i})']
   jql_list_two_str.append(jql_str_2)
```

To then get the relevant strings you are interested in I should think you should use:

```
created = []
resolved = []

for idx, day in enumerate(jql_day):
    
    if idx == 0:
       string1 = jql_list_one_str[idx][0]
       string2 = jql_list_one_str[idx][1]
    else:
       string1 = jql_list_one_str[idx][0] + " , " + jql_list_two_str[idx-1][0]
       string2 = jql_list_one_str[idx][1] + " , " + jql_list_two_str[idx-1][1]

    resolved.append(string1)
    created.append(string2)

print(resolved)
print(created)
```

Comment: HI! Im trying add 
# jql_request = [' '.join(x) for x in zip(jql_list_one_str[1:], jql_list_two_str[:-1])]# Split list
# jql_request.insert(0,jql_list_one_str[0])
for my strings to be like in the condition (I added an image to the question just now)

Comment: update image in question

Comment: i get an error :
    for idx, day in jql_day:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Comment: Apologies, should be ``` for idx, day in enumerate(jql_day):````

Comment: hmm, now i get an error :

string1 = jql_list_one_str[i][0]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Ahh sorry, should be `idx` in place of `i` in most. See update

Comment: Philip , i added your updated code and i added my result output in image "second result"(attach)

Comment: Okay, it appeared to be missing an `f`. That should be corrected now.

Comment: Philip thank you very much! It worked for me! (only string1 and string2 need to be removed : + " , "  )

Comment: No worries! Glad to be of some help!